# Missing EAN code prestashop

Tags: prestashop

I have a problem with the export of products from prestashop to ebay "missing ean code"

How can I add / generate a random EAN code to all my PrestaShop 1000 products?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**The quickest way to edit many products at once is to use the "Import" feature.**
You can use it to edit your products' EANs only.

You can find it in the "Advanced parameters" tab.

1. First, do a backup, always !
2. Download the csv template for product import, available on the right side in the import page or use the file you used to import you catalog (be sure it is up-to-date)
3. Keep only the ID and EAN columns in the file,
4. Use your product IDs and add a fake EAN code (it can be the same for all products) **Be sure it is 13 numbers long**,
5. Save your csv file and import it following the steps in the Prestashop Back Office, **select yes for "Force all ID numbers"**

Your products EANs will be updated.

Hope it helps :)

---

***/!\ Be careful when importing a file with forced ID, it overwrites existing info. If you have existing EANs on some products they will be modified. /!****

Answer (score 0):

Can you please explain little more your problem about how can you export your products or from where you are exporting? So that, I can give you exact solution for this problem.

If you want general solution, please look into below code:

Open your product class file: **root_directory/classes/Product.php**

Edit the following function:

```
public function __construct($id_product = null, $full = false, $id_lang = null, $id_shop = null, Context $context = null) {  

  parent::__construct($id_product, $id_lang, $id_shop); 

  if (empty($this->ean13)) {
      $this->ean13 = $this->generateEAN13(); //New function
  } 
  //Remaining part of this function keep same
}
```

Add New function in this file to generate EAN13:

```
public function generateEAN13() {  
    $length = 13;  
    $ean_number = '';
    $chars = '0123456789';
    $maxlength = Tools::strlen($chars);
    $i = 0;
    while ($i < $length) {  
       $char = Tools::substr($chars, mt_rand(0, $maxlength - 1), 1);
       if (!strstr($code, $char)) { 
           $code .= $char;
           $i++;
       }
    }  

    //Check whether this ean alread exist or not for product
    $sql = 'SELECT id_product FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'product where ean13 = "'.pSQL($code).'"';  
    if ((int)Db::getInstance()->getValue($sql) == 0) {  
        return $code;
    } else {  
        //Check ean13 on combination
        $sql = 'SELECT id_product_attribute FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'product_attribute where ean13 = "'.pSQL($code).'"';  
        if ((int)Db::getInstance()->getValue($sql) == 0) {  
             return $code;
        }
    }  

    return $this->generateEAN13();
}
```

The above code will give you product with ean13 number whenever you get the product data and product has no EAN13.

Comment: HI, thank you...my products not have a EAN code, i want export my products on ebay...but ebay require EAN code for all products.

Comment: I need to generate a ean code for new products and existing products

Answer (score -1):

Please edit Product.php class file there is a function with name priceCalculation()

This function calculates and adds the tax to product price using the following code:

```
if ($use_tax) {
        $price = $product_tax_calculator->addTaxes($price);
    }
```

and

```
$price += $ecotax_tax_calculator->addTaxes($ecotax);
```

You can add some conditions for the manufacturer to get the desired result.